# Using Netbeans plugin in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, netbeans, fxml

Hey just a quick Question:

Is it possible to use a Netbeans plugin inside a Eclipse Project? - I could not find anything on the internet about this :/

This: http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/68619/fxml-2-java-converter

Or maybe someone knows how to use the fxml 2 java converter without an eclipse implementation.

Any help would be appreciated.

~ Faded

Comment: No, that will not run in Eclipse. It doesn't look anything like a Eclipse plugin.

Comment: Oh okay thanks I'm just gonna convert it manually then.